# Error trying to serialize a list of objects in my interface

Tags: c#, user-interface, serialization, xmlserializer

I am working at an application in C#. I have a class DirectorVideo(video directors) and an interface class. In tha interface class i need to serialize the list of video directors but i receive the following error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: There was an error reflecting type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ProiectC.DirectorVideo]'.

DirectorVide class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProiectC
{   [Serializable]
    public class DirectorVideo: FunctiiFisier, IComparable<DirectorVideo>, ICloneable
    {
       public FisierVideo[] fisiere { get; set; }
       public String cale { get; set; }
       public int nrFisiere { get; set; }

        public DirectorVideo(FisierVideo[] fisiere, String cale, int nrFisiere) {
            this.fisiere = fisiere;
            this.cale = cale;
            this.nrFisiere = nrFisiere;

        }
        public DirectorVideo(DirectorVideo dir) {

            this.cale = dir.cale;
            this.nrFisiere = dir.nrFisiere;
            this.fisiere = dir.fisiere;

        }

        public int CompareTo(DirectorVideo other)
        {
            var caleOrder = this.cale.CompareTo(other.cale);
            return caleOrder;
        }

        public object Clone()
        {
            var newDirector=(DirectorVideo)MemberwiseClone();
            newDirector.cale=(String)cale.Clone();
            newDirector.nrFisiere = newDirector.nrFisiere;
            newDirector.fisiere = new FisierVideo[newDirector.nrFisiere];
            for (int i = 0; i < newDirector.nrFisiere; i++)
                newDirector.fisiere[i] = (FisierVideo)fisiere[i];
            return newDirector;
        }

        public DirectorVideo() {

        }


        public DirectorVideo(string cale) {
            this.cale = cale;

        }

    public override List<string> listFiles(string path)
    {        bool ok=false;
            String[] extensions = {".webm", ".mkv", ".flv", ".vob", ".drc", ".gif",
            ".gifv", ".mng", ".avi", ".mp4", ".wmf", "mpeg"};
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);//Assuming Test is your Folder
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.*"); //Getting Text files
            string str = "";
            List<string> files=new List<string>();
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                str = file.Name;
                string ext = extension(str);
                ok = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < extensions.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (ext.Equals(extensions[i]))
                        ok = true;
                }
                if (ok)
                    files.Add(str);



            }
            if (files != null)
                return files;
            else {
                files.Add("Nu a fost gasit nici un fisier video");
                return files;

            }

        }

        public override int countFiles(string path)
        {
            int count = 0;
            bool ok = false;
            String[] extensions = {".webm", ".mkv", ".flv", ".vob", ".drc", ".gif",
            ".gifv", ".mng", ".avi", ".mp4", ".wmf", "mpeg"};
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);//Assuming Test is your Folder
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.*"); //Getting Text files
            string str = "";
            List<string> files = new List<string>();
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                str = file.Name;
                string ext = extension(str);
                ok = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < extensions.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (ext.Equals(extensions[i]))
                        ok = true;
                }
                if (ok)
                    count++;
            }
            return count;
        }

        public override string extension(string file)
        {
            return Path.GetExtension(file);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {   if (this.fisiere != null)
                return string.Format("{0}", string.Join<FisierVideo>("\n", fisiere));
            else
                return ("Folderul nu contine fisiere video");
        }

        public static List<DirectorVideo> operator+(List<DirectorVideo> directoare, DirectorVideo dir)
        {
            directoare.Add(dir);
            return directoare;
        }
    }
}
```

Interface class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ProiectC
{   [Serializable]
    public partial class Interfata : Form
    { public DirectorVideo dir { get; set; }
        public List<DirectorVideo> directors { get; set; } = new List<DirectorVideo>();

        public Interfata()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnCale_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            DirectorVideo dir = new DirectorVideo();
            string cale = txtCale.Text;
            int nrFisiere = dir.countFiles(cale);
            List<string> fisiereLista = dir.listFiles(cale);
            FisierVideo[] fisiere = new FisierVideo[fisiereLista.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < nrFisiere; i++)
                fisiere[i] = new FisierVideo(fisiereLista[i]);

            DirectorVideo director = new DirectorVideo(fisiere, cale, nrFisiere);
            //cloneable
            this.dir = (DirectorVideo)director.Clone();
            DirectorVideo combo = null;
            bool ok = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < comboBox.Items.Count; i++)
            {   //comparable
                combo = new DirectorVideo(comboBox.GetItemText(comboBox.Items[i]));
                if (this.dir.CompareTo(combo) == 0)
                    ok = false;

            }
            if (ok == true)
            {
                comboBox.Items.Add(cale);
                this.directors.Add(this.dir);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(directors.Count);
        }

        private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.directors.Count; i++)
            {
                if (this.directors[i].cale.Equals(comboBox.Text))
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < this.directors[i].nrFisiere; j++)
                        listView.Items.Add(this.directors[i].fisiere[j].numeFisier);
                }
            }
        }

        private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DirectorVideo>));
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("SerializedXML.xml"))
            { serializer.Serialize(writer, this.directors); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) What is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the message, traceback, type **and InnerException**?  2) Can you try to simplify your question down to a more [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that could be tested as a console app?  You've got a lot of GUI code there which seems extraneous.

Comment: You might look at [Troubleshooting Common Problems with the XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all of the properties of the class you are attempting to serialize are serializable as well, and have public getters/setters.  For example, your type `FisierVideo` also needs to be serializable.  If there are properties that you do not want serialized, decorate them with the `XmlIgnoreAttribute`.

```
[XmlIgnore]
public FisierVideo[] fisiere { get; set; }
```

Comment: The problem is on System.Collections.Generic, but i cant understand why

Comment: `[Serializable]` has no effect on `XmlSerializer`.  Rather, to serialize a type with `XmlSerializer`, it must be public, and have a public parameterless constructor.